# Nginx proxy pass subdomain, node vhost

Tags: node.js, nginx, subdomain

I have some trouble with nginx proxy_pass redirection on localhost subdomain. I have a domain "domain.com", i want to redirect all request on *.domain.com on *.localhost:9000. Then node handle all request on *.localhost:9000 to the good express app.

On nginx conf when i try the following :

```
server {
    server_name extranet.domain.com;
    listen 80;
    location / {
       proxy_pass http://extranet.localhost:9000;
    }
}
```

Request on `extranet.domain.com` are well redirected to the good express webapp.

With this :

```
server {
    server_name ~^(.*?)\.domain\.com$;
    listen 80;
    location / {
       proxy_pass http://localhost:9000/$1;
    }
}
```

Express app running on `localhost:9000` handle request /mysubdomainname, which implie that regex is good.

But when i try :

```
server {
    server_name ~^(.*?)\.domain\.com$;
    listen 80;
    location / {
       proxy_pass http://$1.localhost:9000;
    }
}
```

All request on *.domain.com return http code 502.
Why `http://localhost:9000/$1;` works and not `http://$1.localhost:9000;` ?
(all subdomain are set in `/etc/hosts`).

Thanks in advance. I'm totally lost !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a host name isn't known at run-time, nginx has to use its [own resolver](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#resolver). Unlike the resolver provided by OS, it doesn't use your `/etc/hosts` file.

Comment: Thanks, 
So the only way to do what i want is to add 
server {
     server_name : subdomain1.domain.com;
     listen: 80;
     location / {
           proxy_pass http://subdomain1.localhost:9000;
    }
}

for each subdomain ?

Comment: Or configure your own local dns server.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this will give you a hint, I wanted to pass the subdomain from Nginx to an Express app. Here is my code:

nginx.conf

```
http {

upstream express {
  server localhost:3000;
}
```

domain.com inside nginx/sites-available

```
server {

listen 80;
server_name ~^(?<subdomain>.+)\.domain\.com$;

location / {
   proxy_set_header Subdomain $subdomain;
   proxy_set_header Host $host;
   proxy_pass http://express;
 }
}
```

Express app index.js

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    const subdomain = req.headers.subdomain;
});

app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log('Example app listening on port 4000!');
});
```